# Table View Cell Image Retina Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a table view that displays custom cells with an image of the item.  I allow the user to choose a photo from there library, which will be displayed on the cell.  The image is saved in the documents directory.

I am confused on how to handle the retina vs non-retina displays.

Let's say my image is 70 x 70 pixels, should I also keep a 140 x 140 pixel version for the retina display.  What's an appropriate way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should have a 70x70 px file and a 140x140 px one also. If you name your normal image "CellImage.png", you should name the retina one "CellImage@2x.png".

Comment: when I create the cell, and assign it an image should I just load CellImage.png?  The right image will be pulled depending on the device

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing the user to choose the image from their library I am assuming that you are resizing the image before placing it in the Documents directory.

If you are sure that the images will not be shared between different devices (as in iCloud) then you can simply save the image in the correct scale and forget about it.  i.e. scale the image appropriately for the current device.

You could just save the image at 140x140 and have the presentation properly scaled by the size constraints of theUIImageView.

I don't know if imageWithContentsOfFile works the same way as imageNamed method or not but when calling the imageNamed method you don't specify the file's extension but rather just the bare filename and the method attempts to select the correct file without you having to specify the decorations i.e.
 Image.png
 Image@2x.png
 Image~iphone.png
 Image@2x~iphone.png